# random shuffle of columns

Tags: r, random

I have a file that has two columns and an indefinite number of rows.
row 1 includes a person id, 
row 2 includes a score for each person id.
I am trying to randomly shuffle the scores and randomly reassign them to person id in a new 2 column data frame.
basically destroying the real relationship between score and person id.
How can I do this in R?
I'm not sure how to write a function that does this
thanks.

Comment: Are you just looking for `?sample`

Comment: -1 for a basic lack of research effort.

Comment: What they said. This returns a 'permutation'.

Comment: Importantly, if you doing this for some basic calculation, great.  However, if your goal is to anonymize your data, please know that this will absolutely __not__ accomplish that goal.

Answer (score 3):

As @Dason said in the comments it looks like you are just looking for sample. I have to say this is pretty basic stuff and even a rudimentary google query (or with your other favourite search engine) would have given you many posts and links on how to do this.

I assume that your data is in `data.frame` called `data` and it has a column called `"id"` for the person IDs and a column called `"score"` for the scores. You can easily make a new data.frame using sample like so...

```
data2 <- data.frame( ID = sample( data$id , nrow( data ) ) , Score = sample( data$score , nrow( data ) ) )
```

Comment: upvote for taking the time to answer the question.